# ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [POST] "/locations/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Routes

`resources :locations, :only => [:new, :create]`

Controller

```
 class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @location = Location.new
  end

  def create
    @location = Location.new(location_params)

    if @location.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Created location successfully'
      redirect_to new_location_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'Invalid information. Please try again'
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def location_params
    params.require(:location).permit(:name, :street, :city, :state)
  end
end
```

Error message when I click save.

```
 ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [POST] "/locations/new"
```

view

```
<%= simple_form_for :locations do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :name %>
  <%= form.input :street %>
  <%= form.input :city %>
  <%= form.input :state %>

  <%= form.submit 'Create location' %>
<% end %>
```

Using capybara to test that when I click on save it creates a new location. I'm not quite sure why it doesn't know what the post route is because I have the new and create routes. If I put a binding.pry right underneath the create method it doesn't get called. So my create method is not being called for some reason.

EDIT:

Rake Routes

```
locations    POST   /locations(.:format)                        locations#
new_location GET    /locations/new(.:format)                    locations#new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the views.

```
<%= simple_form_for :locations do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :name %>
  <%= form.input :street %>
  <%= form.input :city %>
  <%= form.input :state %>

  <%= form.submit 'Create location' %>
<% end %>
```

I was calling on locations symbol when I should have been calling on the instance variable @location from the controller.

The actual problem was that rails 3.2.12 doesn't take private params

Comment: There seems to be a lot of example code on the web in which form_for and the like are used with symbols.

Answer (score 1):

A resource normally GETs to `new` and POSTs to `create`.  So your form is probably submitting back to the new actions instead of submitting to the create action.

Here's the guide for this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Answer (score 0):

Using `resources`, the `new` action should be fetched with `GET` instead of `POST`. `create` will be `POST`. Check your `rake routes`